# What's the alternative of onAfterLayout() of GXT2 in GXT3?

Tags: gxt

I migrate a project from GXT2 to GXT3. I can't find an alternative of the method onAfterLayout(). Any one have an idea please?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to onAttach handler with a schedule deferred wrapped around a function should provide the behavior you want in the next event loop.

```
final GridWithRadiosWidget grid = new GridWithRadiosWidget();
grid.asWidget().addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
    if (grid.asWidget().isAttached()) {
      Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
          // Do something in the next event loop after it's rendered
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And another option is to extend the layout container and extend onResize.